# wget to get list of files

Tags: bash, wget

I am using `wget` in a bash script to get a list of files from a website, the files are sequential and in the format `http://example.com/00001.csv` etc.

Is there a way to terminate/end the script when I hit the last file?

This is the script I have so far.

```
#!/bin/bash 
url="example.com"; 
for a in {00000001..18923230} do 
wget -nc -q ${url}$a.csv 
done
```

Comment: Do you have any script? It would be good if you post the script and then ask the question.

Comment: #!/bin/bash
 
url="http://site.com"

 
for a in {00000001..18923230}
do
 
    wget -nc  -q ${url}$a.csv
   
done

Comment: Add an echo statement after done.

Comment: its going to be run on a cronjob so ideally it needs to terminate when it gets the first http 404 rather than iterating from 1 to  18923230 each time it runs (every 2 hours)

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way would be to check if the file exists. Using your current script:

```
#!/bin/bash 
url="example.com"; 
for a in {00000001..18923230}
do 
    wget -nc -q ${url}$a.csv || exit;
done
```

That will exit as soon as one of the files is not downloadable. Alternatively, assuming there is an `index.html` file that links to these, you could download that and `grep` for the file names.

Comment: @devnull fair point, I used `exit` 'cause the OP said it should _terminate_ whet it gets the 1st 404.

Answer (score 2):

`wget` appears to return 0 when successful and non-zero otherwise, so:

```
    wget blahblah
    if [[ $? -ne "0" ]]; then
        break;
    fi
```

...inside your `for` loop.

Comment: Or you could just do
if ! wget blahblah; then...
or even better, what terdon did in his comment.